# Bootstrap 3 only for mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site `1600px` wide and I want to make that fit nicely on mobile only. How can I do with Bootstrap 3. I tried to use `col-sm-*`. but also effects on larges screens because existing site is not coded as per Bootstrap grid. Is there any way I can use Bootstrap without effecting large screen?

Answer (score 131):

### If you're looking to make the elements be 33.3% only on small devices and lower:

*This is backwards from what Bootstrap is designed for*, but you can do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">.col-xs-4 .col-md-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">.col-xs-4 .col-md-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">.col-xs-4 .col-md-12</div>
</div>
```

This will make each element 33.3% wide on small and extra small devices but 100% wide on medium and larger devices.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/sggt8/embedded/result/

### If you're only looking to hide elements for smaller devices:

I think you're looking for the `visible-xs` and/or `visible-sm` classes. These will let you make certain elements only visible to small screen devices.

For example, if you want a element to only be visible to small and extra-small devices, do this:

```
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm">You're using a fairly small device.</div>
```

To show it only for larger screens, use this:

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">You're probably not using a phone.</div>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes for more information.

Comment: no Joshua. I am not looking for these kind of classes. Let me give me a example: Like I have 3 divs in the markup with sm class. <div class="col-sm-4"></div> <div class="col-sm-4"></div> <div class="col-sm-4"></div> the with of each div would be 33.3 as per BS on small screen. but on the larger screen i do not want these 33.3 width. means col-sm-4 should work onl for small screes not large screens like above 678.

Comment: @Monkviper Bootstrap isn't designed to work like that. The `col-sm-4` class is designed to make it 33.3% only at small and above, not small and below.

Comment: you can include all of the classes that apply if you want it to be 33% at small size you do col-sm-4, but if you want it to be say 66% at medium size you would do col-md-8. In the same class like so: class="col-sm-4 col-md-8"

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution wich is to do:

```
<span class="visible-sm"> your code without col </span>
<span class="visible-xs"> your code with col </span>
```

It's not very optimized but it works. Did you find something better? It really miss a class like col-sm-0 to apply colons just to the xs size...

Answer (score -1):

You can create a jQuery function to unload Bootstrap CSS files at the size of 768px, and load it back when resized to lower width. This way you can design a mobile website without touching the desktop version, by using col-xs-* only

```
function resize() {
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap.min.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap-theme.min.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
}   
else {
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap.min.css"]').prop('disabled', false);
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap-theme.min.css"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(resize);
resize();   

if ($(window).width() > 767) {
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap.min.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="bootstrap-theme.min.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
});
```

Comment: This is very complicated and unusual way. You can use a simple mediaquery (https://mediaqueri.es) to do the job to you ;)