# Use totally different nav menu in mobile collapsed (responsive) vs desktop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design, navigation

I'm using Boostrap 3 but have a side by side menu that I want stacked for mobile / responsive screen mode. Is there a way to use / show a totally different navigation menu in the mobile versions of my site? the example bootstrap code below is the menu button for mobile devices. When clicked the menu is displayed differently from desktop versions. how do I have a totally different nav menu / code displayed when clicking on the button?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w54fphvy/)**

Comment: You're not getting what I'm saying, I already know it does that. But it's still using the same menu in mobile vs, desktop it's just positioned differently. I am trying to get it use a totally different menu for mobile (depending on media query screen size). One that is hidden on desktop versions but when in mobile and you hit the button with the 3 horizontal bars you get a different menu, with different menu items/names for example. I tried this with the same code  as above and changed the data-target to go for the id with the "hidden"  menu but it did not work.

Comment: Here's another way to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167723/bootstrap-3-only-for-mobile

Answer (score 2):

create two separate drop downs ad a unique class to each for example `class="desktop"` and the other `class="mobile"` in your css have mobile class hidden like this `.mobile{display: none;}` then at your media query where you want your different dropdown to show do this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: somewidth here){
.desktop{display: none;}
.mobile{display: inline;}
}
```

This will hide your desktop dropdown and then show your mobile version.

Comment: Thanks, much better answer than the one above, you were actually able to understand a pretty simple question.

Comment: @StoryTech The proper way to indicate that an answer solved your problem is to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Doing so will also prevent your question from being [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) in the future with all of its answers.